# Can xcarchive be opened on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I received an xcarchive of an app. I would like to check it on my device and then distribute. How can it be installed on the iPhone?

Comment: This is certainly on topic, as it relates to testing of an Xcode build product on a device.

Comment: This is certainly possible in 2023, but I'm unable to post an answer because the question is "closed." 1. Right-click xcarchive, choose "Show Package Contents." 2. Go to Products > Applications. 3. Copy application somewhere. 4. In Xcode go to Devices and Simulators. 5. Select desired device. 6. Click the little "+" button under Installed Apps. 7. Select the application file copied earlier.

Comment: @ChuckBatson was that specific to an older version of Xcode, I don't see "installed apps" in 14.3.1

Comment: @Craig I'm still seeing it in Xcode 14.3.1. Unsure why it doesn't show up for you. Maybe there's an alternate way to do the same thing (i.e. menu item)? Or perhaps the device needs to have developer mode enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't install an xcarchive on an iPhone. Ask the person that sent it you to send a ipa file instead.

Comment: If the **xarchive** is properly signed then there should not be any problem in installing it on the device.one can always find the .app found in archive and **drag and drop in iTunes** to make the **ipa** and install in the device via iTunes or one can easily install the .app through **xcode devices** and he can even use the archive to open up xcode archives and re-sign the app with his own signers.I don't see a problem with this.He has to be careful about entitlements though if available

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H is correct, this is indeed entirely possible, and not difficult. See my comment under the question.

Comment: Without any signer one can install from xarchive ?